# Hide soft Keyboard in Android after a custom dialog dismiss

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard, customdialog

I'm in a situation in which I have an editText. When I press add in the edit text i'm adding a member in a list. When is added (or not) I'm opening a custom Dialog.

In my activity i have this code when clicking on add button in the edit text:

```
  customDialogTeamMember = new CustomDialogTeamMember(............);
  customDialogTeamMember.makeDialog();
  editText.getText().clear();
  editText.clearFocus();
  hideSoftKeyboard();
```

My hideSoftKeyboard() is defined like:

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

This method works in other sections of the app. But here is not working!

The custom dialog opens. When i close it the keyboard keeps on the screen. What could be the problem?!

Comment: Did you override onDismissDialog in your activity and call hideSoftKeyboard(); within it?

Comment: Refer this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show and hide Keyboard

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//Hide:
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
//Show
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);




private void hideKeyboard() {   
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}

private void showKeyboard() {   
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// minimize keyboard
    try {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(dialog.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this on my Case.

```
// for hide keyboard
    public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager iim = (InputMethodManager)
                activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null)
            iim.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
```

call this method as your requirements.and let me know..Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check if no view has focus:
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
     InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
     imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Check this out

Answer (score 0):

To hide and show the soft keyboard,use the following method

```
private void hideKeyboard() {   
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}

private void showKeyboard() {   
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
}
```